# Compile time error: undefined reference to 'CTetrisGame::Create()'

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, compiler-errors

I'm fairly new to programming in c++ and I've come across some code which gives me errors because the code was intended for a windows operating system, however I'm running a linux operating system. There's a file called TetrisBlock.h, which looks like:

```
#ifndef TETRIS_BLOCK_INCLUDED
#define TETRIS_BLOCK_INCLUDED

#include "Common.h"

class CTetrisBlock
{
  public:
      void Create();
      void Draw();
      void Destroy();

      CTetrisBlock();
      virtual ~CTetrisBlock();

      int GetPosX();
      int GetPosY();

      void SetPosX(int x);
      void SetPosY(int y);

  private:
      int m_iPosX, m_iPosY;
};

#endif
```

from my experience with java, this looks like an interface to me, waiting for a .cpp to implement it and fill in the abstract methods. The corresponding TetrisBlock.cpp file is as follows:

```
#include "TetrisBlock.h"

CTetrisBlock::CTetrisBlock()
{
    int num_blocks_x = WINDOW_WIDTH / (BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACING);
    int num_blocks_y = WINDOW_HEIGHT / (BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACING);

    m_iPosX = num_blocks_x / 2;
    m_iPosY = num_blocks_y - 1;
}

CTetrisBlock::~CTetrisBlock()
{
    Destroy();  
}

void CTetrisBlock::Create()
{

}

void CTetrisBlock::Draw()
{
    tRect quad;
    quad.m_iLeft = m_iPosX * (BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACING) + BLOCK_SPACING;
    quad.m_iRight = quad.m_iLeft + BLOCK_SIZE - BLOCK_SPACING;
    quad.m_iTop = m_iPosY * (BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACING) - BLOCK_SPACING;
    quad.m_iBottom = quad.m_iTop - BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACING;

    glColor3d(1,1,1);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(quad.m_iLeft, quad.m_iBottom, 0);
    glVertex3f(quad.m_iRight, quad.m_iBottom, 0);
    glVertex3f(quad.m_iRight, quad.m_iTop, 0);
    glVertex3f(quad.m_iLeft, quad.m_iTop, 0);
    glEnd();
}


void CTetrisBlock::Destroy()
{

}

void CTetrisBlock::SetPosX(int x)
{
    m_iPosX = x;
}

void CTetrisBlock::SetPosY(int y)
{
    m_iPosY = y;
}

int CTetrisBlock::GetPosX()
{
    return m_iPosX;
}

int CTetrisBlock::GetPosY()
{
    return m_iPosY;
}
```

Note: The OpenGL library has already been imported within the common.h file

When I compile the file TetrisBlock.cpp, I get the error lines in the console:

undefined reference to 'CTetrisBlock::Create()'

undefined reference to 'CTetrisBlock::Draw()'

undefined reference to 'CTetrisBlock::Destroy()'

etc...

I'm guessing that the way I've filled in the abstract methods only works on windows, and that there's a different way to do it in linux. If this is true, then how would I fill in those abstract methods on linux. If I'm completely wrong, then can anyone explain why I'm receiving these errors. Also, are .h files always used the same way interfaces are used in java, or do they have a more general use?

Comment: This is not compile but link time error

Comment: Do you know why the code fails to link the methods from different files?

Comment: Most probably you do not specify that file (TetrisBlock.cpp) in the project so it is not linked.

Comment: do you know where I can learn more about how the methods are filled in with the function name "datatype Class::methodName()"

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the question, methods are filled in?

Comment: For example in the file TetrisBlock.cpp, The code CTetrisBlock::CTetrisBlock(){//code} is used to "fill in" the constructor for the class CTetrisBlock. The constructor, just like all other methods in the class were stated in the TetrisBlock.h file, but weren't "filled in" till we create the TetrisBlock.cpp file. Sorry, I'm struggling to explain what I mean by filled in

Comment: You should learn basics of the language first. There is no "fill in", there are declarations and definitions. You should learn what they are, how they are used, what is compile and link and so on.

Comment: www.cplusplus.com is a good resource for reference and tutorials. If I can ask, what commands are you using to compile this code? That is most likely where the error is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile error from tetris example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412434/compile-error-from-tetris-example)